# Having issue setting up Hadoop

Tags: installation, hadoop

The issue I'm having is that when I run `bin/hadoop fs -ls` it prints out all the files of the local directory that I'm in and not the files in hdfs (which currently should be none). Here's how I set everything up:

I've downloaded and unzipped all the 0.20.2 files into `/home/micah/hadoop-install/`. I've edited my `conf/hdfs-site.xml` with the following settings and created the appropriate directories:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/micah/hdfs/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/micah/hdfs/name</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I then ran `bin/hadoop namenode -format` followed by `bin/start-dfs.sh`.

Comment: What happens if you try: 

`bin/hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000` ?

Comment: 11/03/11 16:54:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).

Comment: It keeps retrying and gives me the error message above

Comment: That would indicate it's not running (which, however, is not what you're asking ... but that should work if hdfs was up)

Comment: so I ran `bin/stop-all.sh` followed by `bin/start-all.sh` and it gives a bunch of `localhost: starting ....` and doesn't appear to fail.

Comment: I found an article but it doesn't make any sense to me. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/200907.mbox/%3C6D826992-B9B8-43C0-9769-912B0AA7787F@gmail.com%3E

Comment: Doesn't apply to you - you're running and accessing as the same (unix) user. You need to figure out why it's not coming up (or not coming up on 127.0.0.1 on port 9000). When you supply the `hdfs://host:port` to `bin/hadoop` you're seeing that it can't connect. There is no `hdfs-file.xml` in `conf` ... did you mean you edited `hdfs-site.xml` ?

Comment: Look for useful error messages under your log directory in the *namenode* and *datanode* files.  By default the log directory is $HADOOP_HOME/log.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    #http://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg00407.html
    rm -r /tmp/hadoop****
    build $HADOOP_HOME
    echo export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME >> $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh
    echoThenRun "$HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh"
    echoThenRun "$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found that my `HDFS` data directory permissions were wrong.

Removing group write privileges with `chmod -R g-w` from the data directory fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks , Doing the following resolved my issue

```
rm -r /tmp/hadoop****
    build $HADOOP_HOME
    echo export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME >> $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh
    echoThenRun "$HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh"
    echoThenRun "$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format"
```